# How to get the URI of a file that I downloaded with download manager?

Tags: android, uri

I use download manager to download .ogg file. 
I use this code to download it:

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription(list.get(position).getName());
            request.setTitle(list.get(position).getName());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, list.get(position).getName() + ".ogg");

            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
```

Now I want to share this file so I need his uri.

How can I get this file uri?

Answer (score 5):

Method `DownloadManager.enqueue()` returns an Id ([DOC IS HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#enqueue(android.app.DownloadManager.Request))). So, you must "store" that id for future operations (such as consult the Uri of the downloaded file).

This way, you can use that Id to get the `Uri` if the file was downloaded successfully using `Uri getUriForDownloadedFile(long id);` ([DOC HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#getUriForDownloadedFile(long)))

**EDIT**

If you created a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive broadcasts about a completed download, you can get the Uri as soon as your file has been downlaoded:

```
private int mFileDownloadedId = -1;

// Requesting the download
DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
mFileDownloadedId = manager.enqueue(request);

// Later, when you receive the broadcast about download completed.
private BroadcastReceiver onDownloadComplete = new BroadcastReceiver() {
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       long downloadedID = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
       if (downloadedID == mFileDownloadedId) {
           // File received
           DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
           Uri uri = manager.getUriForDownloadedFile(mFileDownloadedId);
       }
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(onDownloadComplete, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // Don't forget to unregister the Broadcast
}
```

Comment: where is downloadedID initialized?