# Open PDF after download with DownloadManager and FileProvider on Android Q (10)

Tags: java, android, mobile, native

targetSdkVersion: 30

In our App we have a feature, where we download files (mostly pdf) to the public download folder and start an intent afterwards to open it. Our code works fine for android apps with api <= 28 and >= 30. Just our app on Android 10 (sdkVersion 29) will try to open the document and instantly closes the activity that tried to display the pdf. The logcat shows following error:

```
22-03-17 14:23:42.486 12161-15168/? E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
22-03-17 14:23:42.486 12161-15168/? E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : download.pdf] +ContentOpenable, uri: content://com.example.fileprovider/Download/download.pdf
```

If I grant the files permission in the app settings, it will work flawlessly but if I understood the android documentation correctly this should not be necessary since Android 10. Especially because there are no problems on Android 11 and Android 12 devices that do not have this permission. On all Android versions the file will be downloaded correctly and the user could manually open it from the download section of his device.

This is the Android Manifest section for the fileprovider

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"        
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

The filepaths XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
    <external-path
        name="Download"
        path="Download/"/>
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
    <external-cache-path
        name="external_cache"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

This is the code with the DownloadManager usage to download the files

```
public static long downloadFile(Context context, String url, String fileName) {
    DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

    try {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setTitle(fileName)
                .setDescription(Localization.getStringClient("file_download_progress"))
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        return downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, Localization.getStringClient("error_downloading_asset"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return -1;
}
```

The broadcast receiver that listens on the download progress

```
public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private long downloadId = -2;

    public void setDownloadId(long downloadId) {
        this.downloadId = downloadId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (id == downloadId) {
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(id);
            Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                    String mediaType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));
                    Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(uriString);

                    DownloadUtils.openFile(context, fileUri, mediaType);
                } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Localization.getStringClient("error_downloading_asset"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code to open the file. Only on Android 10 the app closes the activity instantly again.

```
public static void openFile(Context context, Uri fileUri, String mediaType) {
    File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            context,
            context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider",
            file
    );

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, mediaType);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, Localization.getStringClient("open_file_no_activity"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And a download call in the looks like this

```
@Override
public void startPDFDownload(String pdfDownloadUrl, String fileName) {
    long downloadId = DownloadUtils.downloadFile(requireContext(), pdfDownloadUrl, fileName);

    if (downloadId > -1) {
        DownloadBroadcastReceiver receiver = new DownloadBroadcastReceiver();
        receiver.setDownloadId(downloadId);
        requireContext().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }
}
```

I think I have a false understanding of how file handling works in Android 10 but I do not know where I have to adjust the code or configuration. Help is really appreciated. Currently as a workaround we ask for the permission for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE to open downloaded files on Android 10. But I would prefer to do it the right way.

**Solution:**

I adjusted the BroadcastReceiver to the following code. I removed the LOCAL_URI from the cursor and used the URI from the DownloadManager method.

```
public class DownloadBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private long downloadId = -2;

    public void setDownloadId(long downloadId) {
        this.downloadId = downloadId;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        long id = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
        if (id == downloadId) {
            DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(id);
            Cursor c = downloadManager.query(query);
            if (c != null) {
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    String mediaType = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_MEDIA_TYPE));

                    DownloadUtils.openFile(context, downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(id), mediaType);
                } else if (DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, Localization.getStringClient("error_downloading_asset"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                c.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I adjusted the method to open the file with the uri to following code. I removed the FileProvider code and used the uri from the DownloadManager.

```
public static void openFile(Context context, Uri fileUri, String mediaType) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, mediaType);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(context, Localization.getStringClient("open_file_no_activity"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The code of the other methods remains the same.

Comment: Hello @jplabs , is it possible to edit your question and append the solution? Thank you!

Comment: The solution is appended @Panayotis. I hope this helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use FileProvider to obtain an uri for your file.

You can get an uri from DownloadManager and use it to serve your file.

Code would be the same for all Android versions.

Not a single permission needed.

Comment: Wow this works flawlessly. Thank you so much, I wasted several hours today on this issue. It's really confusing to work with files on android since they change the security and permission handling so often.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but I use code similar to : ` Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(Uri.parse(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))));

                startActivityForResult(new Intent().setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                        .setDataAndType(uri, mime)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION), registerGlobally(listener));`  but it doesn't work.    Any ideas? Hints?

Comment: Do not use Uri.fromFile() if you have already an uri.

Comment: @jplabs Sorry for the noise! Indeed if I use this methodology instead https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53069828/how-to-get-yhe-uri-of-a-file-that-i-downloaded-with-download-manager it works flawlessly! Thank you -- you're a lifesaver.